# My Pandas and OpenAI Program isn't storing column values

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api

I am trying to create an OpenAI and Pandas integrated program that takes values and a user input to generate a chat response and loads the responses into the second column on the excel. Not sure what's up, but the program isn't working. It runs for like 10 minutes before hitting a bad gateway error. Can someone explain to me what I may be doing wrong w my code? EDIT: It is working now, but now it's not storing my Column Values

There's less than 100 rows in the column for the test.

I expected my code to store the values in the second row of my excel file.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openai

# Set up your OpenAI API credentials
openai.api_key = "MYKEY"


def store_column_values_to_excel(file_path, sheet_name, column_name):
    # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # Get the values from the specified column
    column_values = df[column_name].tolist()

    return column_values


def generate_chat_prompt(column_values, user_input):
    prompt = "User: " + user_input + "\nAI: "

    for value in column_values:
        prompt += "\nUser: " + user_input + value + "\nAI: "

    return prompt


def store_responses_to_excel(file_path, sheet_name, column_name, responses):
    # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # Add a new column for storing responses
    df["AI Response"] = responses

    # Save the updated DataFrame to the Excel file
    df.to_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)


# Specify the Excel file details
file_path = "MYFILELOCATION"
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
column_name = "URLs"

# User input for ChatGPT
user_input = input("User: ")

# Store column values from Excel
column_values = store_column_values_to_excel(file_path, sheet_name, column_name)

# Generate the chat prompt
chat_prompt = generate_chat_prompt(column_values, user_input)

# Specify the parameters for the ChatGPT API call
chat_params = {
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": user_input},
    ],
    "max_tokens": 100,
    "temperature": 0.7,
}

# Interact with ChatGPT
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(**chat_params)
ai_response = response.choices[0].message["content"]

print("AI:", ai_response)

# Store AI responses in the second column of the Excel file
store_responses_to_excel(file_path, sheet_name, "AI Response", [ai_response])
```

Here's what I'm getting:
openai.error.APIError: Bad gateway. {"error":{"code":502,"message":"Bad gateway.","param":null,"type":"cf_bad_gateway"}} 502 {'error': {'code': 502, 'message': 'Bad gateway.', 'param': None, 'type': 'cf_bad_gateway'}} ....

The bad gateway issue is fixed, but now it is not storing the column values:
User: Given the following URL, does this company...
AI: I'm sorry, but you haven't provided a URL for me to review. Please provide the URL so I can assist you better.

Comment: Have you inspected `df` and `response` before and after the `df["AI Response"] = responses` line in the `store_responses_to_excel` function ? Looks like you should pass a list of values, while you're passing `[ai_response]`.

Comment: Yeah I just needed to add an s to the responses because that's what the list is called. thank you!

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.